# How te keep only lines that has a capital letter atleast

Tags: notepad++

i want to keep only the lines that has 1 capital letter or more
exemple:

```
zerhdydeki
ijuedHded
uuuuinfr
iLP
```

Result

```
uuuuinfr
iLP
```

Thank you

Comment: `uuuuinfr` haven't capital letter in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a typo in your result.

This will remove all lines that don't have any capital letters in them.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^A-Z]+(?:\R|$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  [^A-Z]+       # 1 or more capital letters
  (?:\R|$)      # any kind of linebreak or end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
ijuedHded
iLP
```